# Hot Deployment with WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2

Can I do a hot deployment in WSO2 ESB. As an example I want add a new service / new route without restarting the ESB to minimize the service interruption.

If possible can you give any example.

If not possible can I know if it will be in future releases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hot deployment/hot update may take the system to inconsistent states if the updates are not properly coordinated. Therefore it is recommended to turn hot deployment and hot update off for production deployments.
More Details [here](http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB470/FAQ#FAQ-Whataretheimplicationsofhotdeploymenthotupdateinaproductionenvironment)